# AJAX is not returning a flask render_template, It sends the data but stops just before rendering it

Tags: javascript, python, flask

Hi everyone and thanks for viewing my question, I'm trying to build and application using Flask to send html,css and js file paths to flask (after open() & read() the files content) send them to html and view the codes there.

I'm using AJAX to post a data to this url: "/getFiles" ; the data is being sent successfully and printed but the code is stopping just before returning.

> I tried Axios but had the same exact results.
>
> > I tried to change *contentType: "application/json" **to**  contentType: "json"*  but the code stopped working then.
> >
> > > I tried to render to another page different than index.html but that didn't help as well.
> > >
> > > > I tried to return just with `return "OK" , 200` but even this didn't work.

I've done a simplified version of the code to let you focus on the problem.

here is my python code:

```
from flask import *

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=["GET"])
def homepage():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/getFiles', methods=['POST'])
def getFiles():
    data = request.get_json()
    print(data)
    htmlFile = data['html']
    cssFile = data['css']
    jsFile = data['js']
    return render_template('index.html', html=htmlFile, css=cssFile, js=jsFile)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run("0.0.0.0", port=5500)
```

and here's my HTML code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>html files :</p>
    <p>{{ html }}</p>
    <p>css files :</p>
    <p>{{ css }}</p>
    <p>js files :</p>
    <p>{{ js }}</p>
    <button id="clickMe">Bring Data</button>
  </body>

  <script>
    $("#clickMe").on("click", function () {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/getFiles",
        type: "post",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify({
          html: "html files",
          css: "css_files",
          js: "js files ",
        }),
      })
        .done(function (result) {
          console.log("message sent!");
          $("#data").html(result);
        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log("failed to send! ");
        });
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

When I'm running my code this is what I get in Python logs

```
C:\Users\z420\Desktop\small test>python views.py
 * Serving Flask app 'views' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on all addresses.
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
 * Running on http://192.168.147.110:5500/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jul/2021 15:44:50] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
{'html': 'html files', 'css': 'css_files', 'js': 'js files '}
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jul/2021 15:44:51] "POST /getFiles HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

*data is printed but no rendering...*

Comment: How the code stopped returning , is there any error. Please paste the python logs here. Please give the exact problem you are facing.

Comment: * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on all addresses.
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
 * Running on http://192.168.147.110:5500/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jul/2021 15:42:37] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
{'html': 'html files', 'css': 'css_files', 'js': 'js files '}
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jul/2021 15:42:39] "POST /getFiles HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Comment: as you see above my data is being printed but `return render_template('index.html', html=htmlFile, css=cssFile, js=jsFile)` is not being initiated

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68225226/edit) your question to include the logs for the ease of reading.

Comment: If that is only your html code then I don't see any element with id data. Check if you have element with Id data

Comment: I am taking about element with id `data` which you used in .done function in `$("#data").html(result)`

Comment: oh yes, actually this part stayed from my main code I can get rid of it since it has nothing to do with posting the data.

Comment: After you make a ajax request the result is returned to javascript , this means `result` in `.done` function has the returned data. Try `console.log(result)` in `.done` function.

Comment: That printed all my html code in the console.
You can see and test my code online from this link :

https://replit.com/join/dhagqsgosm-shahemm
**login required

Comment: Ya I know it will print that's what i said in last comment. what really you want to do , print  names like this - html files : html files , css files: css_files , js : js files on the webpage? or something else.

Comment: Yes I want these 3 words to be printed on my html page where I placed the jinja codes. (this is a simplified version of my project but making it work will fix my main project problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to show the file names. you have to return the file names in python dict.
and use javascript to show them on webpage.

```
[...]
return {"html":htmlFile,"css":cssFile,"js":jsFile}
```

replace the `p` tags with a div with id files  `<div id="files"></div>`

in js(jquery):

```
.done(function (result) {
      console.log("message sent!");
      console.log(result)
      $("#files").html(`<p>html files :</p><p>${result.html}</p><p>css files :</p><p>${result.css}</p><p>js files :</p><p>${result.js}</p>`)})
```

this will edit and display the content you want.